# Quickblox simple chat app

Tags: ios, chat, quickblox

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/igorkhomenko/workspace/quickblox-ios-sdk/Framework'
ld: library not found for -lPods
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am new to ios development and quickblox
I get this kind of error..what it is about ? M i missing to add some file .

Answer (score 1):

you seem to have used [cocoapods](http://cocoapods.org) to add this library to your project.

Cocoapods creates, and requires you to use, an `xcworkspace` file to manage your Xcode project.

This is an error that occurs when you are still using the `xcodeproj` file instead of the `xcworkspace`.

Either that or your cocoa pods setup is broken. Try running `pod install` again or see the website to fix it.

Comment: is it important to use cocoa pod file or podfile with quickblox ?

Comment: cocoapods is an optional tool you can use to integrate 3rd party code into your project. You don't have to use it, but if you have several 3rd party libraries it can make managing them easier.

Comment: tree.h file not available when i add quickblox framework to new project with qb settings ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the quicklblox library through Target Settings -> Build Phases -> Link binary with libraries -> + button?

Comment: Want to check if you have made the changes in Other Linker Flags as suggested in  [link]http://quickblox.com/developers/IOS-how-to-connect-Quickblox-framework